# Is it possible to deploy SSIS 2012 package on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a package that is developed in SSIS 2012 using Visual Studio 2010.

- Is it possible to deploy/attach this package on SQL Server 2008
- If it is possible, does the licence of the sql server matter

Comment: One should not, as a rule, develop on a newer edition of anything than is running on production. Unless you are getting the upgrade to the new version ready.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I it a bit annoying to develop in VS2008, so we are considering the options.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

no, you cant. SSIS package are not backwards compatible.

Also it doesn't make much sense if you think about it. If it was the other way around, "maybe" it could be done because 2012 would somehow be aware of 2008 structure, but 2008 engine isn't aware of 2012 package structure.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot run it with the 2008 version of dtexec and you certainly cannot deploy it into the catalog, but if you could install the minimum you need to run SSIS 2012 onto a server somewhere you could then execute the package from filesystem with the 2012 version of [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx).

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Best guess would be no.  The engine to run the SSIS package would have to match the release level of the code.  You have not been able to run any SSIS package on any release level below the developed level of the package (i.e. 2005 server will not run a 2008 package etc.)

It is not a license issue, it is an engine issue.  The SSIS engine code changes with each release and therefore the code would be running in an engine that doesn't support the features or structure of the package.