# Create SSIS for SQL2008 with VS2010 and SQL2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to deploy SSIS 2012 package on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499290/is-it-possible-to-deploy-ssis-2012-package-on-sql-server-2008)

currently I have Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012 on my pc. Now I want to create a SSIS package, which should run on a SQL Server 2008.

If I create it normally, I just get the following error, if I try to load it on the server:

> The package failed to load due to error 0xc0010014 "[...]" This occurs
>   when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

If I try to open it with BIS 2008, then I get a similar error.

Is there any way to change my dtsx so that it will work on a SQL Server 2008?

Comment: This is why you never create code in a version of the software higher than the one you intend to use. You must create packages in BIDS 2008. You also should NOT be developing against a 2012 database if your production db is 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Packages have changed since 2008 : the XML structure is not the same. Packages created for SQL Server 2012 will only run for that technology. To have a 2008 package, create it using BIDS 2008.

Comment: Thanks, not my favorite answer, but I guess the correct one. :)