# SSIS 2017 running on Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, compatibility, ssis-2008, sql-server-2017

We are discussing a partner and I about SQL Server, SSIS and other topics and the following question has arisen:

Can I develop an SSIS of 2017 and run it in SQL Server 2008 R2? (this question is already answered). Apart from the .NET version and performance, what are the big differences between the SSIS 2017 and SSIS 2008 R2? Is it worth updating the version?

Understand that we do not have equipment and software on hand to prove it (we are eating).

A greeting!

Comment: [Is it possible to deploy SSIS 2012 package on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499290/is-it-possible-to-deploy-ssis-2012-package-on-sql-server-2008#10499912)

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question adding some more, in case you want to answer also: D

Comment: 2012 introduced various levels for parameters, for instance project parameters, where 2008 only has package parameters.  That's a nicety, but I don't know that there is a situation where package parameters are insufficient.  I think you'll find that nearly all of the changes between versions are that way, but you'll have to pore over the update change logs to really know for sure.  Are there specific features you are worried about not having on 2008?

Comment: 2008 is approaching End of Life, meaning Microsoft won't support it anymore.   That's the biggest reason to upgrade, IMO.

Comment: @AaronDietz On the contrary, it is to know that I am lost because I can not update to a newer version.